# Get unique count of column values in VBA based on filtering another column

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet where there are 7 columns. I need to get unique count of users(in column A) based on filtering column C(Active - A, Inactive - I). Example

```
User_ID  Status
A1        A
A2        I
A1        A
A3        I
A2        I
```

Currently, I am using below code to get total count of the column but I need to first filter Status=A, then get unique count of column User_ID if any duplicates are there in column A. I searched on the internet but was not able to find any proper solution, I am very new to VBA so kindly help.

```
DSheet.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

> Collection

```
Private Sub Test()
Dim Test As New Collection
Dim Test1 As New Collection
Dim rng As Range
For i = 2 To 6 'replace 6 with last row number
    Value = Cells(i, "A").Value
    check = Contains(Test, Value)
    check1 = Contains(Test1, Value)
    If Cells(i, "B").Value = "A" And Not check And Len(Value) > 0 Then
        MsgBox Value
        Test.Add Value, CStr(Value)
    ElseIf Cells(i, "B").Value = "I" And Not check1 And Len(Value) > 0 Then
        Test1.Add Value, CStr(Value)
    End If
Next i
On Error GoTo 0
MsgBox Test.count ' Distinct count for Status A
MsgBox Test1.count ' Distinct count for Status I
End Sub

'Function to check if the value exists in collection.
Public Function Contains(col As Collection, key As Variant) As Boolean
Dim obj As Variant
On Error GoTo err
    Contains = True
    obj = col(key)
    Exit Function
err:

    Contains = False
End Function
```

Comment: can you pls explain in short the code written in For loop.

Comment: I have used two collections. One for `Status=A` and one for `Status=I`. Then i am inserting values in both the collections based on the condition that it should not be there in respective collection by using `Contains Function`. This way items in both the collection will be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your help. I was able to execute through shorter code. I am filtering one column and getting unique counts based on filtered values. Sharing the code:

```
SSheet.Range("$A:$S").Autofilter field:=2, Criteria1:="A"
Set List=CreateObject(Scripting.Dictionary)

For Each ids In SSheet.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
 If Not List.Exists(ids.Value) Then List.Add ids.Value, Nothing
Next
MsgBox List.count
```